# BottomNavigationView запретить пересоздание фрагмента

Tags: android, bottom-navigation-view

Использую у себя шаблон студии `BottomNavigationView` 
в нем 4 фрагмента и данные загружаются из `Firebase`.

Столкнулся с такой `фичей`, если нажимаешь на первый `item` (или на любой), фрагмент пересоздается. 
Но как мне правильно сделать проверку на то, что бы текущий фрагмент не пересоздавался заново если он выбран в данный момент?

Мой код -

```
 private Fragment fragment;


private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_main:
                fragment = new MainFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                fragment = new PagerTaxiFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_intercity:
                fragment = new PagerBus();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                fragment = new MainTrainFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};


private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.contentLayout, fragment).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение - 
Создал три фрагмента в качестве членов класса и повторно их использовал.

```
 private final Fragment mFirstFragment = new MainFragment();
private final Fragment mSecondFragment = new PagerTaxiFragment();
private final Fragment mThirdFragment = new PagerBus();
private final Fragment mFourFragment = new MainTrainFragment();
```

Ну и вот так обработал:

```
 if (navigation.getSelectedItemId() != item.getItemId()) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_main:
                    loadFragment(mFirstFragment);
                    return true;...итд


private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.contentLayout, fragment).commit();
```

}